# Using PHP inside of CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Im trying to have a text line popup once the comment button is clicked for each line(row) dynamically.

When you click on the comment button, a line should popup under the buttons within the same row.

On DOM inspect, the lines and buttons all have unique names and id's

I just cant get it to work as a unique event for each row.

[Here is an image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trU2E.png)

```
<div class="container-xxl flex-grow-1 container-p-y">
             
<h2 align="center"><?php echo $appname?></h2><br />
   <div class="form-group">
   <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
                    
   <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
         <?php while ($checks = mysqli_fetch_array($checksqry)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td style="width: 20%">'.$checks['check_name'].' <br><br> 
            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btn[' . $checks['id'] . ']" id="btnpass[' . $checks['id'] . ']" value="Pass">
            <label class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-success" for="btnpass[' . $checks['id'] . ']">Pass</label>&Tab;&Tab;
                    
           <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btn[' . $checks['id'] . ']" id="btnwarning[' . $checks['id'] . ']" value="Warning">
           <label class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-warning" for="btnwarning[' . $checks['id'] . ']">Warning</label>&Tab;&Tab;
                    
           <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btn[' . $checks['id'] . ']" id="btnfail[' . $checks['id'] . ']" value="Fail">
           <label class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-danger" for="btnfail[' . $checks['id'] . ']">Fail</label>&Tab;&Tab;
                    
           <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button" name="comment[' . $checks['id'] . ']" id="comment[' . $checks['id'] . ']" class="btn btn-info" style="float: right"><img src="assets/comment.png" width="20px"></button> 
<br><br>
           <div id="commentlinediv[' . $checks['id'] . ']">
           <input type="text" class="text-line" placeholder="Type Comment Here" id="commentline[' . $checks['id'] . ']"/>
</div>
</td>';
echo '<tr>';}?>
                        
</table>
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

```
input[type="text"] {
   border:none; /* Get rid of the browser's styling */
   border-bottom:1px solid black; /* Add your own border */
}

.text-line {
   background-color: transparent;
   color: black;
   outline: none;
   outline-style: none;
   border-top: none;
   border-left: none;
   border-right: none;
   border-bottom: solid #eeeeee 1px;
   padding: 3px 10px;
   width: 300px;
}
                
#commentlinediv[<?php echo $checks['id']?>]{
   display: none;
}
```

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("commentlinediv[<?php $checks['id']?>]").style.display = "inline";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) You should pass the variable of `$checks['id']` to your myFunction so that the system knows which div should be changed from hidden to inline, so change the JS to

```
<script>
function myFunction(var1) {
  
document.getElementById("commentlinediv[" + var1 + "]").style.display = "inline";
}

</script>
```

2. Instead of specifying the commentlinediv as hidden, you may simply put it inline

So the whole code will be like:

```
<div class="container-xxl flex-grow-1 container-p-y">
             
<h2 align="center"><?php echo $appname?></h2><br />
   <div class="form-group">
   <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
                    
   <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">

   <?php while ($checks = mysqli_fetch_array($checksqry)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td style="width: 20%">'.$checks['check_name'].' <br><br> 
            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btn[' . $checks['id'] . ']" id="btnpass[' . $checks['id'] . ']" value="Pass">
            <label class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-success" for="btnpass[' . $checks['id'] . ']">Pass</label>&Tab;&Tab;

           <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btn[' . $checks['id'] . ']" id="btnwarning[' . $checks['id'] . ']" value="Warning">
           <label class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-warning" for="btnwarning[' . $checks['id'] . ']">Warning</label>&Tab;&Tab;

           <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btn[' . $checks['id'] . ']" id="btnfail[' . $checks['id'] . ']" value="Fail">
           <label class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-danger" for="btnfail[' . $checks['id'] . ']">Fail</label>&Tab;&Tab;

           <button onclick="myFunction('. $checks['id'] . ')" type="button" name="comment[' . $checks['id'] . ']" id="comment[' . $checks['id'] . ']" class="btn btn-info" style="float: right">Click</button> 
<br><br>
           <div style="display:none;" id="commentlinediv[' . $checks['id'] . ']">
           <input type="text" class="text-line" placeholder="Type Comment Here" id="commentline[' . $checks['id'] . ']"/>
</div>
</td>';
echo '<tr>';}?>

 </table>
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>

<style>
input[type="text"] {
   border:none; /* Get rid of the browser's styling */
   border-bottom:1px solid black; /* Add your own border */
}

.text-line {
   background-color: transparent;
   color: black;
   outline: none;
   outline-style: none;
   border-top: none;
   border-left: none;
   border-right: none;
   border-bottom: solid #eeeeee 1px;
   padding: 3px 10px;
   width: 300px;
}
                


</style>


<script>
function myFunction(var1) {
  
document.getElementById("commentlinediv[" + var1 + "]").style.display = "inline";
}

</script>
```

Comment: I changed what you had said, but it still isnt functioning within my code. Will this work inside of the PHP while loop?  Not sure what im doing wrong and its driving me insane! Lol

Comment: I see how your solution works when its just pure html, but it appears to not function inside of the while loop

Comment: Your revised code shows the comment line on each row, its not hidden. I changed the style of the div to display: none. But it still doesn't function.  I appreciate your patience and your help! I hope we can get this to work!

Comment: Your code was copied and pasted. The comment line is hidden but when the comment button is clicked, nothing happens, it does not appear.

Comment: Please see my further revised answer (with a Demo Link) - copy and paste the code and re-try in your site please . Thanks

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much!!! Ive spent 3 days straight, no sleep, trying to figure this out!! What was your changes??

Comment: Sorry to bug you again. But how do I send the filled out check to mysql? I know how to post and send to mysql, but not in the while loop when everything is is dynamic

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78170694/php-post-to-mysql-with-dynamic-table-inside-while-loop